# Scaling iBus as well as other windows

Tags: kubuntu, ibus, resize

[image: This is the super small iBus]
Note that the toolbar (after a 200% scaling) is 8mm high, but the iBus panel is as small as it, which is unacceptable. How to let it also scale?

###### OS Details

- DPI: 96
- Resolution: 2736x1824
- Computer: Microsoft Surface Pro 4
- OS: Kubuntu 21.10
- KDE Plasma: 5.86.0
- KDE Framework: 5.86.0
- Qt: 5.15.2

###### Current setup

- Global zoom: 200%
- Toolbar: 200%
- Cursor: 48px (original 24px)

Comment: It worked for no reason...